# Android SpannableString in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, textview, baseadapter, spannablestring

I have an Adapter with a TextView. The TextView either contains a String, or a SpannableString, depending on whether the text is clickable or not. However, I have noticed that when the view is recycled, sometimes it looses its click ability. I think the SpannableString becomes a String again.

Does anyone knows why this is or have any suggestions on how to fix? I am using a ViewHolder, (in case anyone was wondering) as well as a CustomObject (that handles what type of String to return).

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final ViewHolder tag;

    if (view == null) {

        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, viewGroup, false);

        tag = new ViewHolder(
                (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1),
                (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1),
                (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2),
                mItems.get(pos));

        view.setTag(tag);

    } else {
        tag = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    tag.item = mItems.get(pos);

    tag.tv1.setText(tag.item.getName());
    tag.tv2.setText(tag.item.getMsg());

    return view;
}

private final class ViewHolder {
    private final TextView tv1, tv2;
    private final ImageView iv;
    private CustomObject item;

    public ViewHolder (ImageView iv, TextView tv1, TextView tv2, CustomObject item) {
        this.iv = iv;
        this.tv1 = tv1;
        this.tv2 = tv2;
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

~~ EDIT ~~

It turns out that the issue was in how I was parsing the string for links. I check the string for multiple links, and I have a flag which is checked depending on whether it has reached the end of the string. The flag is still set to finished when the view is recycled, so it didn't reformat (despite being stored as a final processed SpannableString object in my CustomObject). Now I have it set to reset the flag, so it can process again if necessary. Not sure why it needs to re-process some of the time though.

Comment: Have You tried to use 2 types of views instead of one using getViewTypeCount()?

Comment: @sandrstar, I'm not sure what you mean. I understand how to use 2 types of views, but for using 2 different layouts. Both Strings and SpannableStrings should be loaded into a TextView, so I don't see a need for a separate layout for each. I appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: As one view type has some spannable content and another just plain text, they might be treated as two different types of view. Seems there's some TextView property get triggered then you changing content type. I believe, your issue will be fixed if You try 2 type of views.